# Name error in python while calling out other functions in another function variable, already defined in function which is called but says undefined

Tags: python

I have just started with python
I wrote the following code and I am getting name error
Can someone please help out and tell me what the problem is?

```
print("A is addition \nB is subtraction \nC is multiplication \nD is division")

def number():
 x=int(input("Enter a number: "))
 y=int(input("Enter a number again: "))

def funcA():
 number() 
 z=int(x)+int(y)
 print(str(z))

def funcB():
 number()
 z=x-y
 print(z)

def funcC():
 number() 
 z=x*y
 print(z)

choice=input("Enter desired option: " )

if choice == 'A':
 funcA()
elif choice=='B':
 funcB()
elif choice=='C':
 funcC()
else:
 print ("INVALID")
```

Comment: Which line is throwing the error?

Comment: O wait never mind. x and y are not defined in funcA, funcB, or funcC. Either define x & y as global or pass them as parameters into funcA, funcB, & funcC.

Comment: Please do not indent using one space. Are you trying to save on disk space? You're in trouble if you cannot afford to indent by four spaces.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you define the variables `x` and `y` within the scope of the function `input`, therefore, it is not available in the scope of the `funcA`, `funcB` and `funcC`

You can return the values from your function `number`, and define them within the different functions

Notice that I changed `x` and `y` in the `number` function, and rename it to `input1` and `input2`, to make it clear that these variables, as soon as the `number` function is executed, they get out of scope.

Try with:

```
print("A is addition \nB is subtraction \nC is multiplication \nD is division")

def number():
    input1 = int(input("Enter a number: "))
    input2 = int(input("Enter a number again: "))
    return input1, input2

def funcA():
    x, y = number()
    z = int(x) + int(y)
    print(str(z))

def funcB():
    x, y = number()
    z = x-y
    print(z)

def funcC():
    x, y = number()
    z = x*y
    print(z)

choice=input("Enter desired option: " )

if choice == 'A':
    funcA()
elif choice=='B':
    funcB()
elif choice=='C':
    funcC()
else:
    print("INVALID")
```

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because you are setting your `x` and `y` variables within the `number()` function, and then expecting them to still be "in scope" (i.e. available to reference) from within other functions.

There are a number of ways to resolve this; perhaps the cleanest way would be to define `x` and `y` as [global variables](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/global-keyword-in-python/), although the danger with this is that you can easily lose track of what state the variable is in. I'd go with @rorra's suggestion :)

Answer (score 0):

Function calling is not correct Function a,b and does not know x and y . you have to call them like this .

```
print("A is addition \nB is subtraction \nC is multiplication \nD is division")

def number():
 x=int(input("Enter a number: "))
 y=int(input("Enter a number again: "))
 return x,y

def funcA():
 x,y = number() 
 z=x+y
 print(str(z))

def funcB():
 x,y = number() 
 z=x-y
 print(z)

def funcC():
 x,y = number()  
 z=x*y
 print(z)

choice=input("Enter desired option: " )

if choice == 'A':
 funcA()
elif choice=='B':
 funcB()
elif choice=='C':
 funcC()
else:
 print ("INVALID")
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use a function (in your case number) and inside of it you're working with variables, this variables are "living" inside your function so if you want your other function (like, for example funcA ) to use them you have to return your variables (in your function number) and to save these returned values in your funcA.
There are many ways to pass values between functions, one easy way (applied to your code) for example is:

```
def number():
   x=int(input("Enter a number: "))
   y=int(input("Enter a number again: "))
   return x,y

def funcA():
   x,y =number() 
   z=int(x)+int(y)
   print(str(z))
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem as others said is `return`. You should return `x` and `y` from the `number()` function and remember variables in functions are local and you can use them in the function.

There is another approach that removes redundancy from your code:

```
print("A is addition \nB is subtraction \nC is multiplication \nD is division")

def funcA(x, y):
    z= x + y
    return z

def funcB(x, y):
    z = x - y
    return z

def funcC(x, y):
    z = x * y
    return z

choice=input("Enter desired option: " )
x, y = int(input("Enter a number: ")), int(input("Enter a number again: "))

output = "INVALID"

if choice == 'A':
    output = funcA(x, y)

elif choice=='B':
    output = funcB(x, y)

elif choice=='C':
    output = funcC(x, y)

print(output)
```

Of course, using `return` for functions is so much better than just printing.